How much healing does the Moment of Renewal spell provide?
The Moment of Renewal spell targets up to 6 creatures and says (emphasis mine):

The targets experience a day's worth of recovery in an instant. Any detrimental effects that would be gone after 24 hours end, though this doesn't shorten the duration of any active spells affecting the targets. The targets regain Hit Points and recover from conditions as if they had taken 24 hours of rest, but they do not make their daily preparations again or gain any benefits of rest other than healing. The targets are then temporarily immune for 1 day.

Initially, this seems like it could provide some very potent healing provided the targets have a decent Constitution modifier. However, it is unclear which rules should be followed regarding resting.
Under the rules for Resting, it says that:

...they can gain the benefits of resting only once every 24 hours. A character who rests for 8 hours recovers in the following ways.

The character regains Hit Points equal to their Constitution modifier (minimum 1) multiplied by their level. If they rest without any shelter or comfort, you might reduce this healing by half (to a minimum of 1 HP).
The character loses the fatigued condition.
The character reduces the severity of the doomed and drained conditions by 1.


However, it's possible that the rules for Long-Term Rest apply, which say:

Each full 24-hour period a character spends resting during downtime allows them to recover double what they would for an 8-hour rest. They must spend this time resting in a comfortable and secure location, typically in bed.

So my question is how many hit points does Moment of Renewal recover?
For the sake of simplicity, assume we are healing a 15th level Fighter with a +4 Constitution Modifier and no features that would alter the amount of hit points restored by spells. Does the answer change if the spell is cast in combat (it only takes 2 actions, so it seems viable to do so)?
If we follow the standard Resting rules it seems it would be:

(Level 15) * (Con Mod +4) = 60 hit points

But could the Long-Term Rest rules apply instead despite the lack of a comfortable bed? If so, then it seems it would be:

(Level 15) * (Con Mod +4) = 60 * 2 = 120 hit points

Or do you take the least generous approach and say that the character lacked shelter or comfort and thus it would be:

(Level 15) * (Con Mod +4) = 60 / 2 = 30 hit points

Or is there a different permutation I should consider?

Targets Regain HP as Long-Term Rest
The spell describes targets as regaining health as if they'd taken 24-hours of rest, and the rules describing what happens in that case are for long-term rest.
Requiring that the targets be resting in a comfortable and secure location seems contrary  to the spell's 2-action casting time, as likely used in an active encounter. And given that the full resting happens in that same time, it's similarly not appropriate to reduce the healing for lacking comfort or shelter.
So for your example, a 15th-level fighter with a +4 Con modifier would regain 120 HP even when outside in the middle of a storm fighting a dragon, just as they would if someone cast the spell on them while they were lying on a comfortable bed in an inn.

This can further be increased by Fast Recovery and similar abilities.

It's normal resting hp, double in downtime
If you cast the spell during adventuring, then you use the hp as outlined under resting, Con modifier (min 1) times level.
You gain hit points as if you had taken 24 hours of rest. But the resting rules state that you

can gain the benefits of resting only once every 24 hours. A character who rests for 8 hours recovers in the following ways

So during adventuring, it does not matter if you rest for 8, 16, or 24 hours when you rest, you gain these benefits. Here you rest for 24 hours and gain these benefits.
Long-term rest rules apply only during downtime. If for some unusual reason the spell would be cast during downtime, then you would receive double that (because that is what they would get for 24 hours of rest in downtime).
The rules for downtime state:

Downtime is the space between adventures, where your PCs take a step back before the next chapter starts. [...] Use this mode when the characters return home or otherwise aren't adventuring.

What exactly players do on a day of downtime is not narrowly defined, and spellcasting is not explicitly listed, but the downtime rules say

Characters can undertake their daily preparations if they want, just as they would on a day of exploration.

and this involves regaining spell slots, which would not make sense if you could not cast spells. So you could conceivably have Moment of Renewal as one of your daily preps and declare you cast it every day to speed up the groups healing, while they recuperate in saftey.
Penalties for lacking shelter or comfort would also apply, as you gain hit points "as if you had taken rest", and if you have no shelter or comfort, you would gain less. But it would be rather unusual circumstances for characters that can cast level 8 spells to not be able to afford a room in an inn during downtime.

Can you clarify if the penalties for lacking shelter or comfort would apply?

Also, can you clarify on why you're certain that the standard resting rules apply? I thought it was interesting that the spell's description stated '24 hours of rest' as opposed to either '8 hours of rest' that would more clearly make the standard Resting rule applicable or more general language like 'a full night's rest' which might suggest a rest but not necessarily the kind of rest one receives from resting for 24 hours.

@Pyrotechnical Because these are the standard resting rules. Rest in downtime has other rules, but those apply only during downtime. What other rest rules would you want to apply when not in downtime, but the standard resting rules? I agree they could have worded this maybe somewhat different.

Wouldn't that mean that the spell would do nothing if cast during Encounter Mode (aka combat)? The rules for what happens when you rest for 8 hours is in a section on Exploration Mode, after all.

@RedOrca Hm - maybe. I guess if you look at it like that, you could rule modes do not matter, and you always get standard rest — I don't think the intent is that it wont work in combat.
